# Joining two log tables to get the status of an account at the time it was subject to a logged event

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to join two log tables **using SQL Server 2012**, in order to add status of each account at the time it was subject of an action logged.

The first table is a report created from logs of contact requests from users (to other users) of a website, based on **request date** (`request_date`) and **receiver** (`receiver_account_id`) of the request. If the contact request is approved, then the **approval date** (`approval_date`) column is populated as well. This table looks like this:

```
    receiver_account_id    sender_account_id    request_date    approval_date
    13                     19                   2012-08-10      2012-09-01
    13                     21                   2013-05-15      NULL
    17                     19                   2011-09-11      NULL
    25                     44                   2012-11-05      2012-11-07
```

The second table basically **logs status changes** of accounts:

```
    date        account_id        status
    2011-07-10  13                free
    2012-08-15  13                premium
    2010-12-10  17                free
    2012-05-05  17                premium
    2010-01-20  25                free
    2011-04-10  25                premium
    2012-11-06  25                free
```

I would like to join these two tables, so I can get something like this:

```
    receiver_account_id    sender_account_id    request_date    approval_date    receiver_status_when_received    receiver_status_when_approved
    13                     19                   2012-08-10      2012-09-01       free                             premium  
    13                     21                   2013-05-15      NULL             premium                          NULL
    17                     19                   2011-09-11      NULL             free                             NULL
    25                     44                   2012-11-05      2012-11-07       premium                          free
```

The sender's status is not important at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
;WITH StatusPeriods AS
(
    SELECT account_id, [Status], [date] AS StatusStart, 
        ISNULL((SELECT MIN(Date) FROM status_log nxt WHERE nxt.date > sl.Date AND nxt.account_id = sl.account_id), '2100-1-1') AS StatusEnd
    FROM status_log sl
) 
SELECT request.*, 
    StatusWhenReceived.[Status] AS  receiver_status_when_received, StatusWhenApproved.[Status] AS receiver_status_when_approved
FROM requests 
INNER JOIN  StatusPeriods StatusWhenReceived 
    ON StatusWhenReceived.receiver_account_id = requests.account_id AND requests.request_date between StatusWhenReceived.StatusStart AND StatusWhenReceived.StatusEnd
LEFT  JOIN  StatusPeriods StatusWhenApproved 
    ON StatusWhenApproved.receiver_account_id = requests.account_id AND requests.approval_date between StatusWhenApproved.StatusStart AND StatusWhenApproved.StatusEnd
```

Comment: Does not work: I receive `Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Invalid column name 'account_id'.` for the line where the first inner join is.